# Getting the value of a group in Regex

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

In C# I have the following pattern for my regex:

```
string pattern = "<div class=\"alt\" title=\"[\\w\\s]+\"><strong>([\\w\\s]+)</strong></div>";
```

I create a `Match` object like so:

```
status = Regex.Match(html, pattern);
```

However if I call .groups() on status, I get blank text, even though there's a match. Am I extracting the group correctly?

Edit: Here's some of the HTML,

```
          <tr>
            <td>
                    <div class="alt" title="Released to Manufacturing">
                            <strong>Released to Manufacturing</strong>
```

Comment: What is your `html` looks like?

Comment: `<div class="alt" title="released"><strong>Released</strong></div>`

Answer (score 0):

```
string strRegex = @"<div class=""alt"" title=""[\w\s]+""><strong>([\w\s]+)</strong></div>";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = @"<div class=""alt"" title=""released""><strong>Released</strong></div>";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
    if (myMatch.Success)
    {
        var value = myMatch.Groups[1].Value;
    }
}
```

Verified using [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester)

Comment: I think the problem for me is that the <div> is situated inside a big HTML file, and the Regex is screwing up because of surrounding HTML or something.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not used for parsing html..

Use an html parser like [Htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
   HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
   doc.Load(yourStream);
   var altElementValues= doc.DocumentNode
                            .SelectNodes("//div[@class='alt']/strong")
                            .Select(x=>x.InnerText);
```

Comment: I think this is the right way to approach it. Unfortunately it's not grabbing anything! I'm not sure the problem :( Could you explain how the parameter of `SelectNodes` works?

Comment: @Shazer2 `//div[@class='alt']` is an xpath which would select all div nodes having attribute `class` with value `alt`

Comment: Still retrieves nothing. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39803/discussion-between-shazer2-and-anirudh)